# Wireshark is not displaying http and https packets

Tags: http, https, wireshark

Just wondering why Wireshark is not displaying http or https packets in the view. I am browsing like facebook and other websites to generate http traffic but I don't see any http or https packets..However, I see all of those as TCP or TLS protocols..

Thank you.[Please see the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ugOK.png)

Answer (score 3):

HTTPS means that the content is encrypted.

As Wireshark can not decrypt the content the used protocol inside the TLS connection is unknown to Wireshark - it can be HTTP or any other protocol.

Therefore they are displayed as TLSv1.2/TCP. Only the ports indicate that most likely it is HTTPS traffic.